# Stuck in a redirection loop after upgrading spring ans spring-security version

Tags: java, spring, redirect, spring-security

I have recently upgraded from spring 3.0.5 to 4.1.1 and from spring-security 3.0.5 to 3.2.5 and added csrf support to the application.

In the application a filter makes certain checks and redirects to a change your password page if required. While it was working fine previously it has ceased to work after the above mentioned changes. Now whenever the filter redirects using **response.sendRedirect()** the request is stuck a loop and the browser says **The page isn't redirecting properly**

[image: Request Logs using FireBug]

**web.xml changes**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath*:/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Redirection Filter**

```
String userRole = secUserVo.getRoleName();
  String userType = secUserVo.getSubRoleName();

  if (userRole.equals("ROLE_MERCHANT")) {
    if (userType.equals("MANAGER")) 
      redirectUrl = context + MERCHANT_URL;
    else 
      redirectUrl = context + MERCHANT_SUB_USER_URL;
  } 
  else if (userRole.equals("ROLE_MERCHANT_SALES_ADMIN")) {
    if (userType.equals("MANAGER")) 
      redirectUrl = context + MERCHANT_SALES_URL;
    else 
      redirectUrl = context + MERCHANT_SALES_SUB_USER_URL;
  } 

  response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

**Controller that redirects to the change password screen**

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String initForm(ModelMap model, Principal principal) throws GenericException {
    ChangePasswordVO changePasswordVO = new ChangePasswordVO();
    model.addAttribute("changePassword", changePasswordVO);
    return "merchant/PasswordRecoveryForm";
  }
```

I did try to trace the cause by extensive debugging but that didn't help. Searched over Stackoverflow but that didn't help either. Some of the references that I read are [Getting a Loop Redirect with Spring Security + CAS, but should be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252695/getting-a-loop-redirect-with-spring-security-cas-but-should-be-working) and [Spring security + sendRedirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363378/spring-security-sendredirect-not-working)